# grunt-contrib-coffee one-to-one compile

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

I have several files named:

- jquery.a.b.coffee
- jquery.a.c.coffee
- jquery.a.d.coffee

and they are all compiled into one `jquery.js` file in my output directory.

Although I guess this behavior might be nice in some cases, I would like to have them to compile into different files like `jquery.a.b.js`, `jquery.a.c.js` and so on. How can I tell grunt-contrib-coffeescript to do so?

My Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        coffee: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              cwd: 'app/webroot/coffee',
              src: ['{,*/}*.coffee'],
              dest: 'app/webroot/js',
              ext: '.js'
            }]
          }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');

};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies on the filenames having multiple dots.
If it was *jquery-a-b.coffee*, *jquery-a-c.coffee* etc, you would have seen the expected output.

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/pull/750) (extension is after last period only) and grunt developers made this on purpose.
Here is a quote from one of them:

> There's two ways ext could work; it could consider everything after
>   the first dot the extension, or everything after the last dot the
>   extension. We chose the former because the use-case is more common (we
>   encounter .min.js files all the time). That being said, you can use
>   the rename option to specify a function that will use whatever custom
>   naming logic you need.

So, the only workaround for now is to remove `ext` and use `rename` like this:

```
coffee: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'app/webroot/coffee',
      src: ['{,*/}*.coffee'],
      dest: 'app/webroot/js',
      rename: function(dest, src) {
        return dest + '/' + src.replace(/\.coffee$/, '.js');
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

---

**Update as of Grunt 0.4.3:**
You can now use the [`extDot` option](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) along with `ext`

```
ext: '.js',
extDot: 'last'
```

Comment: Why is 'flatten: true' necessary?

Comment: @KrisKhaira I believe the `flatten` option is not necessary in this case, so I removed it from my answer. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

This works so you don't have to add the files by hand in your gruntFile:

```
coffee: {
    glob_to_multiple: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    cwd: 'app/webroot/coffee/',
    src: ['*.coffee'],
    dest: 'app/webroot/',
    ext: '.js'
    }
},
```

1. **cwd**: the folder where your files are
2. **src**: the matching pattern for your files, using glob
3. **dest**: The folder where your files are going.

See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee#usage-examples for some sample usages

Comment: Aren't there other options, that would be a lot of files to mention

Comment: Okay, this solution doesn't compile anything.

Comment: I have changed the data to match to your needs, what is returned when you execute the **coffee** task ? (With `grunt coffee`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the problem remains: $ grunt coffee
Running "coffee:glob_to_multiple" (coffee) task
File app/webroot/jquery.js created.